# video_editor: ^3.0.0 video Export

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently utilizing the **`video_editor`** plugin with version ^3.0.0 in my Flutter application to perform video trimming and cropping operations. Following the successful implementation of video trimming, my objective is to export the trimmed video to either the phone's document directory or the device's gallery. Unfortunately, I have encountered challenges comprehending the documentation provided for this plugin, as it appears to be less detailed.To address this, I have shared a snippet of my code below, particularly focusing on the **`_exportVideo`** method. I am seeking guidance on how to successfully export the trimmed video and save it to the phone's document directory or, alternatively, to the device's gallery. Your assistance in understanding and refining this functionality would be greatly appreciated.Thanks developer in advance

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:video_editor/video_editor.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class Trim extends StatefulWidget {
  const Trim({Key? key, required this.file}) : super(key: key);

  final File file;

  @override
  State<Trim> createState() => _TrimState();
}

class _TrimState extends State<Trim> {
  late final VideoEditorController _controller;
  late VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;
  int duration = 0;

  String formatter(Duration duration) => [
    duration.inMinutes.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0'),
    duration.inSeconds.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')
  ].join(":");

  final double height = 60;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _videoPlayerController =
    VideoPlayerController.file(widget.file)..initialize().then((_) {
      setState(() {
        duration = _videoPlayerController.value.duration.inSeconds;
      });
    });

    _controller = VideoEditorController.file(
      File(widget.file.path),
      minDuration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      maxDuration: Duration(seconds: 60), // Default value, can be updated later
    );

    _controller.initialize(aspectRatio: 9 / 16).then((_) {
      setState(() {
        // Update maxDuration after _controller has been initialized
        _controller.maxDuration = Duration(seconds: duration > 0 ? duration : 60);
      });
    }).catchError((error) {
      // handle minimum duration bigger than video duration error
      Navigator.pop(context);

    });

  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    _videoPlayerController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  /// Basic export video function
  /// Export a video, with custom command (ultrafast preset + horizontal flip)
// Export a video, with custom command (ultrafast preset + horizontal flip)



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          GestureDetector(
              child: Icon(Icons.save),
            onTap: (){

            },

          )
        ],
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Trim video'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _controller.initialize(aspectRatio: 9 / 16),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return _buildTrimWidget();
          } else {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTrimWidget() {
    return _controller.initialized
        ? Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              CropGridViewer.preview(
                controller: _controller,
              ),
              AnimatedBuilder(
                animation: _controller.video,
                builder: (_, __) => AnimatedOpacity(
                  opacity: _controller.isPlaying ? 0 : 1,
                  duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: _controller.video.play,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 40,
                      height: 40,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      ),
                      child: const Icon(
                        Icons.play_arrow,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        ..._trimSlider(),
      ],
    )
        : const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  }

  List<Widget> _trimSlider() {
    return [
      AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: Listenable.merge([
          _controller,
          _controller.video,
        ]),
        builder: (_, __) {
          final int duration = _controller.videoDuration.inSeconds;
          final double pos = _controller.trimPosition * duration;

          return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: height / 4),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Text(formatter(Duration(seconds: pos.toInt()))),
                const Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
                AnimatedOpacity(
                  opacity: _controller.isTrimming ? 1 : 0,
                  duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Text(formatter(_controller.startTrim)),
                      const SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Text(formatter(_controller.endTrim)),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: height / 4),
        child: TrimSlider(
          controller: _controller,
          height: height,
          horizontalMargin: height / 4,
          child: TrimTimeline(
            controller: _controller,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dependencies:
  flutter_ffmpeg: ^0.5.0
```

To install, run flutter pub get. To utilize flutter_ffmpeg, modify your _exportVideo method as follows:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:video_editor/video_editor.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter_ffmpeg/flutter_ffmpeg.dart';

class Trim extends StatefulWidget {
  const Trim({Key? key, required this.file}) : super(key: key);

  final File file;

  @override
  State<Trim> createState() => _TrimState();
}

class _TrimState extends State<Trim> {
  // ... existing code ...

  Future<void> _exportVideo() async {
    try {
      final Duration start = _controller.startTrim;
      final Duration end = _controller.endTrim;

      final String inputPath = widget.file.path;
      final Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      final String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
      final String outputPath = '$appDocPath/trimmed_video.mp4';

      final FlutterFFmpeg _flutterFFmpeg = FlutterFFmpeg();
      final int returnCode = await _flutterFFmpeg.execute(
        '-i $inputPath -ss ${start.inSeconds} -t ${end.inSeconds - start.inSeconds} -c copy $outputPath',
      );

      if (returnCode == 0) {
        print('Video exported successfully to: $outputPath');
      } else {
        print('Failed to export video, FFmpeg return code: $returnCode');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error exporting video: $e');
    }
  }

  // ... existing code ...
}
```

Furthermore, the video_editor package lacks direct capabilities for exporting reduced videos. If you use the video_editor package for video trimming, you may need to utilize different techniques or packages for video exporting. To obtain export capabilities, try utilizing the video_player package in conjunction with flutter_ffmpeg or other appropriate libraries.

```
import 'package:flutter_ffmpeg/flutter_ffmpeg.dart';

void exportVideo(String inputPath, String outputPath) async {
  FlutterFFmpeg flutterFFmpeg = FlutterFFmpeg();
  
  // Replace this with your desired FFmpeg command for exporting
  String command = '-i $inputPath -c copy $outputPath';

  await flutterFFmpeg.execute(command);
}
```

Comment: there is no  export function in controller this line _controller.export

Comment: The present version of the video_editor plugin appears to lack a straight export function. In such instance, you may use the VideoEditorController to retrieve the trimmed video data and then save it manually to the correct place.

Comment: final Uint8List? trimmedVideoData = await _controller.getTrimmedVideo() on this line   _controller.getTrimmedVideo() there is also no any fuction  which call this getTrimmedVideo().

Comment: If the video_editor plugin does not give an easy way to export the trimmed video, use the flutter_ffmpeg package.

Comment: hey which package you used flutter ffmeg_kit or flutter ffmeg_cli?

Comment: dependencies:
  flutter_ffmpeg: ^0.5.0

Comment: there is no package available _ffmpeg: ^0.5.0 only this package available ffmpeg_kit_flutter: ^6.0.3 and  ffmpeg_cli: ^0.2.0 on pub.dev

Comment: The flutter_ffmpeg package has nothing to do with the video_editor package that you mentioned previously.